# How to memorize sort options in folders?

Tags: pantheon-files

I'm struggling with a few folders in Pantheon Files on Freya which don't keep the sort options I gave them. Especially my Downloads folder. I have to set it to sort its content by date/reverse (so the newest files are on top) every time I open it.

This wasn't a problem on Luna, my sort choice was saved and I didn't have to reset it. On Freya my Pictures folder keeps its files sorted by date (not reverse), Documents keeps by name or by type just as I ask it.

But the Downloads folder doesn't (or rarely more than 2-3 times when I open it). It certainly resets after a reboot, and it also resets in the same session. edit: it resets to 'sort by name'.

Any idea why this particular folder doesn't keep its configuration ?

Thanks in advance,

soda.

Comment: It is not obvious a particular folder should be affected as the code does not distinguish different locations for sorting (except Recent Files), but there was a related bug fixed at revision 1983, which has not been released to Freya.  If its not reproducible then it is probably a race condition.  I could not reproduce this in Loki, the beta of which will soon be released, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the stable version of Loki (now released).